# How to avoid showing many processes on DDMS?

Tags: custom-roms, usb-debugging, processes

### Background

As an Android developer, I use DDMS (link [**here**](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) about what it is), which shows all of the processes that I can debug (along with other stuff).

Today I've finally flashed a custom ROM that is based on AOSP.

### The problem

Ever since I flashed the new ROM, I've noticed that instead of showing just a few processes (including mostly just the apps I'm making), it shows a lot more processes, including both system apps and user apps.

### The question

Is there any way to avoid this from happening?

BTW, I tried putting a tag called "DDMS" and a tag called "AOSP" , and sadly I still can't do it even though my score is quite high on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Izzy This is DDMS : http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html . It's a commonly used tool for developers to handle when devices are connected to the PC. You can take pictures, see the log, choose which process to debug, etc...

Answer (score 0):

DDMS shows the running apps which have the "debuggable" flag set. If the built-in apps are also debuggable, it suggests you're using a debug build of the ROM. Switch to a release build. If the custom ROM you're using doesn't have a release build, switch to a ROM made by people who know what they're doing.

Comment: I've tried out both CM, OmniRom, and PAC-rom. All have this. Also, as I've mentioned, it even shows user apps, such as Whatsapp...